# SQL ERROR Why am I getting "missing right parenthesis"?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having an issue when I try to run my query at the "Round(((..." line of  "missing right parenthesis" and I don't know why. I count three parenthesis on the left, and the close all those parenthesis as the code/line goes on.

I'm running this in Oracle. Just a homework problem dealing with Sub-queries. Here is the HW question if it helps anyone:

> For every direct holder: list the name of the holder, the names of the companies invested in by this direct holder, number of shares currently held, % this holder has of the shares outstanding, and % this holder has of the total authorized shares.  Sort the output by direct holder last name, first name, and company name and display the percentages to two decimal places.

Code:

```
SELECT direct_holder.first_name,
       direct_holder.last_name, 
       company.name,
       current_shareholder_shares.shares,
       ROUND(((current_shareholder_shares.shares/current_stock_stats.total_outstanding)*100, 2) AS "% Owned of Outstanding"),
       ROUND(((current_shareholder_shares.shares/current_stock_stats.current_authorized)*100, 2) AS "% Owned of Total Authorzied")

FROM direct_holder
      JOIN company ON company.company_id = direct_holder.direct_holder_id
      JOIN current_share_stats ON current_stock_stats.shock_id = company.stock_id
      JOIN current_shareholder_shares ON current_shareholder_shares.stock_id = current_shareholder_stats.stock_id
WHERE current_shareholder_shares = (SELECT type
                                    FROM current_shareholder_shares
                                    WHERE type = 'Direct_Holder')
ORDER BY direct_holder.first_name,
         direct_holder.last_name,
         company.name;
```

Comment: . . I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: Why do you have a `WHERE` before your `JOIN` clauses?

Comment: Yea, I fixed the WHERE. That was a mistake on my part

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this... you have wrongly used the ROUND

```
SELECT direct_holder.first_name,
       direct_holder.last_name, 
       company.name,
       current_shareholder_shares.shares,
       ROUND((current_shareholder_shares.shares/current_stock_stats.total_outstanding)*100, 2) AS "% Owned of Outstanding",
       ROUND((current_shareholder_shares.shares/current_stock_stats.current_authorized)*100, 2) AS "% Owned of Total Authorzied"

FROM direct_holder
WHERE current_shareholder_shares = (SELECT type
                                    FROM current_shareholder_shares
                                    WHERE type = 'Direct_Holder')

      JOIN company ON company.company_id = direct_holder.direct_holder_id
      JOIN current_share_stats ON current_stock_stats.shock_id = company.stock_id
      JOIN current_shareholder_shares ON current_shareholder_shares.stock_id = current_shareholder_stats.stock_id
ORDER BY direct_holder.first_name,
         direct_holder.last_name,
         company.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `as` for the column names should be outside all parenthesis:

SELECT

...,

ROUND(((current_shareholder_shares.shares/current_stock_stats.total_outstanding)*100, 2)) as "% Owned of Outstanding",

ROUND(((current_shareholder_shares.shares/current_stock_stats.current_authorized)*100, 2)) as "% Owned of Total Authorzied"

FROM direct_holder

WHERE ...

Comment: That isn't the only problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You have too much parentheses. The ones at the end are not necessary and thus there is one too much at the ROUND statement:

```
   ROUND((current_shareholder_shares.shares/current_stock_stats.total_outstanding)*100, 2) AS "% Owned of Outstanding",
   ROUND((current_shareholder_shares.shares/current_stock_stats.current_authorized)*100, 2) AS "% Owned of Total Authorzied"
```

And even this is too much. Mathematically / and * can executed in the order they appear so:

```
   ROUND(current_shareholder_shares.shares/current_stock_stats.total_outstanding*100, 2) AS "% Owned of Outstanding",
   ROUND(current_shareholder_shares.shares/current_stock_stats.current_authorized*100, 2) AS "% Owned of Total Authorzied"
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SELECT 
direct_holder.first_name,
direct_holder.last_name, 
company.name,
current_shareholder_shares.shares,
ROUND((current_shareholder_shares.shares/current_stock_stats.total_outstanding)*100, 2) AS [% Owned of Outstanding],
ROUND((current_shareholder_shares.shares/current_stock_stats.current_authorized)*100, 2) AS [% Owned of Total Authorzied]
FROM direct_holder
JOIN company 
    ON company.company_id = direct_holder.direct_holder_id
JOIN current_share_stats 
    ON current_stock_stats.shock_id = company.stock_id
JOIN current_shareholder_shares 
    ON current_shareholder_shares.stock_id = current_shareholder_stats.stock_id
WHERE current_shareholder_shares = 'Direct_Holder'
ORDER BY 
direct_holder.first_name,         
direct_holder.last_name,
company.name;
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated

Comment: If this solved the problem @DrewPratt mark it as the solution. It's the best way to show your appreciation and gain reputation.